# UE-V 2.x Agent and support files, where do you get them from?

Tags: windows, agent, user-experience-virtualization

Apologies for such a simple question, but I've been searching for how to download the UE-V 2.x client files for the last few days and all I can find is references on how to install them, nothing on where they are located to begin with.

I must be missing something basic, for anyone who has setup EU-V before can you fill me in on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I followed a link for a beta version of the client and found that it was included in Microsoft Desktop Optimisation Pack. Apologies for wasting your time... and mine